# ASP.NET and PHP in same Website

Tags: php, asp.net, iis

I would like to have an asp.net website hosted in IIS at site like this

```
www.mydotnetsite.com
```

and then have a wordpress blog that is an application to it...

> www.mydotnetsite.com/wordpressblogsite/

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be not a problem. Even some Windows Shared Hosts offer PHP plans - [Windows Hosting](http://www.windowshostingasp.net/Hosting_ASP.NET_plans/Hosting_ASP_NET_PHP.aspx) PHP.

You can configure IIS to support both Asp.Net and PHP at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

yes,you can host your php website in IIS

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible! You can install wordpress in a subdirectory.

- You need to have PHP/MySql configured in your IIS. ([Here is how](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/tutorial-how-install-php-and-mysql-iis-t56303.html))
- You need to point www.mydotnetsite.com/wordpressblogsite/ to the wordpress folder (Download the latest from wordpress.org). In most of the cases, simply copying the folder with the desired name(wordpressblogsite) within the document root of webserver is enough.
- You can then go to the URL and follow the installation option (recommended) OR you can edit the wp-config.php file to put the db credentials etc.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: Yes.

The long answer:

First you're going to have to make sure that PHP and MySQL are installed and working properly on your server and configured for use with IIS. There are installers available to make this process easy. Check out http://php.iis.net/. That will help out a lot with getting PHP up and running as well as installing wordpress. [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) should be easy too, just check out their site and install the correct package.